# How to send GET request sequentially using observables of observables

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I am building a filter where a user is able to filter a list of elements by clicking ion-chips. Every click triggers a call to a external backend using rxjs.
The requests responses should be used sequentially to update the list of elements.
I have a array (filterArray) which contains data of the clicked ion-chips.
This should then be send to the backend.
My first try here creates an observable of said array (observables).
I then map the elements of this observable to a call to getData of my service which triggers a get request returning a observable with the backends response.
This data should then be set in the filter object.

If i push data in to the filterArray nothing happens.
Can anyone give me a hint what might be wrong here?
Thank you in advance!

```
filterArray: any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    const observables = from(this.filterArray);
    const combined = observables.pipe(
      map((filterData) => {
        return this.contentService.getData(filterData);
      }),
      concatAll()
    );
    combined.subscribe(data => {
      this.filter.filteredContent = data;
    });
  }

onChipSelected(val) {
  this.filterArray.push(val)
}
```

Comment: Is the issue still present? Does my answer work?

Answer (score 1):

Your `observables` observable is a cold one, you want a "hot" stream.
One possible way could be to do something like this:

```js
filterArray: any[] = [];
filterArrayObs$: any[] = new BehaviorSubject(this.filterArray);

ngOnInit() {
    const combined = this.filterArrayObs$.pipe(
      map((filterData) => {
        return this.contentService.getData(filterData);
      }),
      concatAll()
    );
    combined.subscribe(data => {
      this.filter.filteredContent = data;
    });
  }

onChipSelected(val) {
  this.filterArray.push(val);
  this.filterArrayObs$.push(this.filterArray);
}
```